# How to check if a file has content or not using C?

Tags: c, file, file-io, lcc-win32

I have a source file `file1` and a destination file `file2`, here I have to move content from  `file1` to `file2`.

So I have to do some validation first.

1. I must check source file is existing or not?
   I can check using this:

   ```
   fp = fopen( argv[1],"r" );
   if ( fp == NULL )
   {
       printf( "Could not open source file\n" );
       exit(1);
   }
   ```
2. Then I have to check if the source file has any content or not? If it is empty, I have to throw some error message.

This is what I've tried until the moment.

Comment: What OS are you working on? Windows?

Comment: `abnormal program termination` so an error? What's the message you're getting?

Comment: @mike: that is msg i am getting in command prompt

Comment: That's the whole message? The program compiles fine then blows up with that? Have you used a debugger to find out where? Did you validate that there's a valid value in `argv[1]` before using it?

Comment: this is the code.....fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
 if ( fp == NULL )
 {
     printf( "Could not open sourse file : argv[1]\n");
  exit(1);
 }
 else
 {
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
  if (ftell(fp) == 0)
   {
       fputs("file is empty",fpout);
   }
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
 }

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/28489691/1340631

Answer (score 18):

C version:

```
if (NULL != fp) {
    fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp);

    if (0 == size) {
        printf("file is empty\n");
    }
}
```

C++ version (stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390912/checking-for-an-empty-file-in-c)):

```
bool is_empty(std::ifstream& pFile)
{
    return pFile.peek() == std::ifstream::traits_type::eof();
}
```

Comment: I/O calls can fail, you should check that `fseek()` and `ftell()` succeed before relying on their results.

Comment: Absolutely! Every C programmer should understand this. I just wanted to simplify my example.

Comment: Keep in mind that this only works for regular files. For special files from /proc/ or /sys/ `ftell()` will always report zero, even if they have content.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this *without* opening the file as well using the `stat` method.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

     struct stat stat_record;
     if(stat(argv[1], &stat_record))
         printf("%s", strerror(errno));
     else if(stat_record.st_size <= 1)
         printf("File is empty\n");
     else {
         // File is present and has data so do stuff...
     }
```

So if the file doesn't exist you'll hit the first `if` and get a message like: `"No such file or directory"`

If the file exists and is empty you'll get the second message `"File is empty"`

This functionality exists on both Linux and Windows, but on Win it's `_stat`. I haven't tested the windows code yet, but you can see examples of it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx).

Comment: Keep in mind that this only works for regular files. For special files from /proc/ or /sys/ the size reported by stat will always be zero, even if they have content.

Answer (score 5):

Just look if there's a character to read

```
int c = fgetc(fp);
if (c == EOF) {
    /* file empty, error handling */
} else {
    ungetc(c, fp);
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that's strictly conforming, portable C code.  Per the C standard, `fseek(..., SEEK_END)` on a binary stream is undefined behavior, and `ftell()` on a text stream returns "unspecified data" that can be used to return to the same position in the file - not a byte offset.

Comment: This is the only answer here that will work for special special files from /proc/ and /sys/. `stat()` and `ftell()` don't work as expected for these files.

Answer (score 3):

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); // goto end of file
if (ftell(fp) == 0)
 {
      //file empty
 }
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); // goto begin of file
// etc;
```

[reference for ftell and example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ftell/)

[reference for fseek and example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/)

Comment: ```rewind()``` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) using `SEEK_END` and then [ftell](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ftell/) to get the size of a file in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the file size > 0

after your code of checking file exist (before you close the file) you add the following code

```
   size = 0
    if(fp!=NULL)
    {
        fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END);

        size = ftell (fp);
        rewind(fp);

    }
    if (size==0)
    {
      // print your error message here
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is painful to open the data and count each byte of the file. It is better to ask to the operating system to give you details about the files you want to used. The API relies depends on your operating system as Mike previously said.