# How do i check if a file is empty in C?

Tags: c, file, input

I'm importing a txtfile into my file, how do i check if the input file is blank.

I already check if it cannot read the input. This is what i have so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

// argv[1] will contain the file name input. 

FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

// need to make sure the file is not empty, error case. 

if (file == NULL){
    printf("error");
    exit(0);
}
 // if the file is empty, print an empty line.

int size = ftell(file); // see if file is empty (size 0)
if (size == 0){
    printf("\n");
}
printf("%d",size);
```

the size checking obviously does not work because i put in a few numbers and the size is still 0. any suggestions?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/13566082/1340631

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `ftell()` does not tell you the size of the file.  From the man page:

> The ftell() function obtains the current value
>   of  the  file  position indicator for the stream 
>   pointed to by stream.

That is, it tell you your current position in the file...which will always be `0` for a newly opened file.  You need to `seek` to the end of the file first (see `fseek()`).

Comment: So do i need to use both ftell() and fseek()?

Comment: Keep in mind that this only works for regular files. For special files from /proc/ or /sys/ `ftell()` will always report zero, even if they have content.

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with a regular file (e.g., a text file), you can use [`sys/stat.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html) and call the value of the `st_size` struct member:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    const char *filename = argv[1];
    struct stat st;
    if (stat(filename, &st) != 0) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "file size: %zd\n", st.st_size);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this only works for regular files. For special files from /proc/ or /sys/ the size reported by stat will always be zero, even if they have content.

Answer (score 2):

how about try read first row.
and see what characters you get?

Answer (score 1):

`ftell` will tell you the **position** the file pointer is at, and immediately after you opened the file, this position is always 0.

You either use `stat` before opening, or use `fseek` to seek some distance in the file (or at end) and then use `ftell`.

Or you delay the check until afterwards. I.e., you *try* to read whatever you need to read, and then verify whether you succeeded or not.

**Update**: and speaking of checks, you have no guarantee that

```
// argv[1] will contain the file name input.
```

For that, you need to check out that `argc` is at least 2 (the first argument being the executable name). Otherwise your file name might be `NULL`. `fopen` should simply return `NULL`, but in other scenarios you might find yourself looking at a core dump.

Comment: Keep in mind that this only works for regular files. For special files from /proc/ or /sys/ `ftell()` will always report zero, even if they have content.