# How to check if csv file has no data?

Tags: c++, csv

I am reading data from a comma delimited csv file. I would like to verify that the file has data before reading and return an error if the file doesn't have any data.

const char* sample_data_file =  "sample_data1.csv" ;
std::ifstream file(sample_data_file);

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking for an empty file in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390912/checking-for-an-empty-file-in-c)

Comment: I tried that, didn't work.
std::ifstream file(sample_data_file);
    if(file.peek() == std::ifstream::traits_type::eof())
     cout<<"empty file"<<endl;

Answer (score 1):

A simple call to [stat](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) will tell you if the file is empty. That should be enough to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

check the size of the file when you open it?

```
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

  ifstream myfile ("C:/temp/sample1.csv");

  // this gives you the number of bytes in the file.

  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
      long begin, end;

      begin = myfile.tellg();
      myfile.seekg (0, ios::end);
      end = myfile.tellg();

      if(end-begin == 0)
      {
          cout << "file is empty \n";

      }
      else
      {
        cout << "size: " << (end-begin) << " bytes." << endl;
      }

      myfile.close();

  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file \n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do I do that?