# C++ Check Eof in Empty File

Tags: c++, file, iostream, eof

I am writing simple program that checks first character of file and print "file is empty" when file is empty

According to this question : [How does ifstream's eof() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533063/how-does-ifstreams-eof-work)
i can compare `ifstream.get()` and `char_traits::eof()` for checking end of file . But following program prints nothing:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

int main(){
  std::ifstream myCin("console.txt");

  if(myCin.get()
     == std::char_traits<char>::eof())
    {
      std::cout <<
        "File is empty" << std:: endl;
    }

  myCin.close();
}
```

Note : console.txt is empty

Comment: You may want to check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2390938/9052234

Comment: Is the file actually empty or does it contain a single blank line?

Comment: thanks alan , you'r right ! the file was not empty